# golang http (or gocraft) rate limit

Tags: http, curl, go

I have a server implementing a REST service using golang's net.http and gocraft.web package.

And I have a client sending JSON request via libcurl, the client is written in C++.

What I notice is that when there are a lot of client threads for sending concurrent JSON requests, there are times when the client gets "Couldn't connect to server" error, but then after a while it can resume sending again.

Since the observation points to rate-limiting, my question is where is rate-limitting happening? Is this at the client side (libcurl), Go's http package, or gocraft.web package?

Comment: Is this all being done on the same machine? If so, is it possible you're running out of sockets?

Comment: This isn't rate-limiting exactly - that implies it's some intentional logic-driven throttling. This is a case of simple resource starvation: insufficient CPU/memory/sockets/ports/file descriptors to service requests.

Comment: Maybe, over SO_MAXCONN's connections.

Comment: no, client and server are in 2 different machines, and there're maximum of about 20 client's sending threads (each issues post/get requests)

Comment: @Adrian, I monitored the server and the messages never get delivered to the REST endpoint/method. They must be dropped before that

Comment: Yes. That's what I would expect with resource starvation.

Comment: did you try to increse net.core.netdev_max_backlog in /etc/sysctl.conf ?

Comment: @Adrian, the CPU at the server was high, then drop to very low during the time when the requests were dropped. That doesn't seem to indicate starvation, does it?

Comment: @math, no i haven't tried that

Comment: @user1734905 not CPU starvation, but that says nothing of all the other resources I mentioned that it might be running out of.

Comment: is there a way to find out which resources were saturated. And where does it happen? At the client side, or at the server side (in this case, it must be in Golang's net package, right?)

Comment: You could use an atomic counter you increment, then `defer` decrement to keep track of how many concurrent connections are running. Obviously this could create more delay by waiting on locks, but it's purpose would be for diagnosing the issue.